# Compute gradient norm of each part of composite loss function

Tags: tensorflow

Assume I have the following loss function:

```
loss_a = tf.reduce_mean(my_loss_fn(model_output, targets))
loss_b = tf.reduce_mean(my_other_loss_fn(model_output, targets))
loss_final = loss_a + tf.multiply(alpha, loss_b)
```

To visualize the norm of the gradients w.r.t to `loss_final` one could do this:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss_final)
grads, _ = list(zip(*grads_and_vars))
norms = tf.global_norm(grads)
gradnorm_s = tf.summary.scalar('gradient norm', norms)
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, name='train_op')
```

However, I would like to plot the norm of the gradients w.r.t to `loss_a` and `loss_b` separately. How can I do this in the *most efficient* way? Do I have to call `compute_gradients(..)` on both `loss_a` and `loss_b` separately and then add those two gradients together before passing them to `optimizer.apply_gradients(..)`? I know that this would mathematically be correct due to the summation rule, but it just seems a bit cumbersome and I also don't know how you would implement the summation of the gradients correctly. Also, `loss_final` is rather simple, because it's just a summation. What if `loss_final` was more complicated, e.g. a division?

I'm using Tensorflow 0.12.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are right that combining gradients could get messy. Instead just compute the gradients of each of the losses as well as the final loss. Because tensorflow optimizes the [directed acyclic graph (DAG)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283757/can-someone-explain-in-simple-terms-to-me-what-a-directed-acyclic-graph-is) before compilation, this doesn't result in duplication of work.

For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.name_scope('inputs'):
    W = tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32, initial_value=tf.random_normal((4, 1), dtype=tf.float32), name='W')
    x = tf.random_uniform((6, 4), dtype=tf.float32, name='x')

with tf.name_scope('outputs'):
    y = tf.matmul(x, W, name='y')

def my_loss_fn(output, targets, name):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(output - targets), name=name)

def my_other_loss_fn(output, targets, name):
    return tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean((output - targets) ** 2), name=name)

def get_tensors(loss_fn):

    loss = loss_fn(y, targets, 'loss')
    grads = tf.gradients(loss, W, name='gradients')
    norm = tf.norm(grads, name='norm')

    return loss, grads, norm

targets = tf.random_uniform((6, 1))

with tf.name_scope('a'):
    loss_a, grads_a, norm_a = get_tensors(my_loss_fn)

with tf.name_scope('b'):
    loss_b, grads_b, norm_b = get_tensors(my_loss_fn)

with tf.name_scope('combined'):
    loss = tf.add(loss_a, loss_b, name='loss')
    grad = tf.gradients(loss, W, name='gradients')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=sess)

    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./tensorboard_results', sess.graph)
    res = sess.run([norm_a, norm_b, grad])

    print(*res, sep='\n')
```

**Edit**: In response to your comment... You can [check the DAG of a tensorflow model using tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/graph_viz). I've updated the code to store the graph.

Run `tensorboard --logdir $PWD/tensorboard_results` in a terminal and navigate to the url printed on the commandline (typically `http://localhost:6006/`). Then click on GRAPH tab to view the DAG. You can recursively expand the tensors, ops, namespaces to see subgraphs to see individual operations and their inputs.

[image: tensorboard DAG example]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do you know that this is being optimized by tensorflow and really no duplication of work happens? Can we verify what optimizations are applied to the DAG somehow? I know I could run some tests, but are there some kind of guarantees that this possible optimization is indeed applied every time or are we relying on "best effort" behavior?

Comment: @kaufmanu updated the answer to show how to capture the graph.